# Array to string conversion error on cakephp cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cookies

I am trying to set a associative array to a cookie variable in cakephp. The array is :

```
$recent_designers = array(
"0"=>
    array(
        "name" => "Hello",
        ),
"1"=>
    array(
        "name" => "Hi",    
        )

);
```

And to set this array to a cookie `recent_designers` :

```
$this->Cookie->write('recent_designers', $recent_designers);
$cookies = $this->Cookie->read('recent_designers'); 
$this->set("recent_designers", $cookies);
```

But I am getting an notice 
`Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE\cake\libs\controller\components\cookie.php, line 458]` on the `ctp`file ! If my array is in this format:

```
$recent_designers = array(
                        "0"=>"Hello","1"=>"Hi","2"=>"Namaste"
                    );
```

I did not get any error.

Comment: Cookies can store string values only. If you want to store values of other type (such as array) you have to `serialize` it on write and `unserialize` on read. Also you can use `json_encode`/`json_decode` instead

Answer (score 0):

you can store a plain array in cakephp using cookie::write, but not a nested array.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html#using-the-component.

Passing an array of 3 elements is the same of saving 3 cookies

so doing

```
$recent_designers = array(
    "0"=>"Hello",
    "1"=>"Hi",
    "2"=>"Namaste"
);

$this->Cookie->write('recent_designers', $recent_designers);
```

is the same of

```
$this->Cookie->write('recent_designers.0', 'Hello');
$this->Cookie->write('recent_designers.1', 'Hi');
$this->Cookie->write('recent_designers.2', 'Namaste');
```